# Why didn't the Druids find Reyn sooner?

Tags: shannara

I've been reading *The Darkling Child*, and I find it odd that the Druids didn't find Reyn much sooner.

> We know that his use of the Wishsong* to kill can be seen after the incident in Portlow. So, why didn't it happen when he was a child? Also, he's been living in Portlow for over 2 years its said. All the while he's using the Wishsong to entertain people.

Why would the Druids scry waters not pick this up at all?

*I put that in spoilers, as this is book two of the series, and I know that it at least threw me off when I read it.